# How can I resolve the printing issue for the document that is modified by apache poi

Tags: java, printing, ms-word, apache-poi

I want to ask a question which is related to apache poi and generated file printing. What I am doing is I am opening a .docx file, inserting some data and saving and printing it.

I am having a file with only 1 table which is something like:
[document table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiKxX.png)

Now, if there are 'n' items, I am generating n-1 rows which copies the format of row 3.

First item is inserted in row 3, if there's another item I am adding a row in the table and saving it likewise I am creating the rows.

Now I want to make this table length = page length. For this I am counting exactly how many rows this page can incorporate and based on that I am inserting empty lines without inside top and bottom border.

The file does not have any header/ footer or any other details as of now.
While I am creating the file I am shown the file which is coming in print preview of covering the whole page of size A4.

But this document is printed only on 80% of paper. I am having 0.3 cm margins but in print the whole page is not printed.
This does not seem to be the printer issue because if other software like Google Chrome are used then it prints the complete page.

So I want to ask that how can I solve this? I tried to search about this but till now I couldn't solve it. I think of this as an issue that whenever I am using XWPFDocument, its margins and all are changed set to default size. I don't know whether this is the issue or something other is, do I need to write some commands to preserve the margins and all or there's something that I need to do.
How can I solve this thing?
Thank you.

Comment: "I am counting exactly how many rows this page can incorporate ": There will always be people who try to squaring the circle, even though it has long been clear that this is not possible. Also, what software is printing the document? `Apache poi` can neither rendering a `Word` document into pages nor printing a such to a printer.

Comment: Sir the software is MS Word. Counting the row meant that if I was creating a table in MS Word, without Apache POI, I calculated that I can get say 25 rows in the document after the fixed part. In the Java code, as you had answered in my first question, I am creating a new row which is similar like the existing row. So I verified that the generated row's height was same as existing one. That's why I tried to generate a total of 25 rows, be it a data row or empty row.

Comment: All the rows are generated in 1 page so there's no issue in that. If in the end there's some space left like 0.2 or 0.3 cm it is acceptable. But what happens is the document is getting printed for around 80% of its content from top. That's why I wanted to ask that if I need to change some settings or am I missing some margin related configuration in coding..

Comment: The more text you are writing here the more unclear is your question for me. How shall anybody be able answering this without knowing what code you are using or at least seeing the document created by `apache poi`? Can you not simply showing the used code and/or uploading the created document somewhere?

Comment: Yes I understood it sorry for that. I am adding the link to the code and the sample getting generated, please go through it and tell me how the printing issue can be solved.     https://drive.google.com/open?id=18N_PPpBUl96oVkx6SqL7dLTb74uErpw4

Comment: Well as I had feared. I assume you are missing the bottom part after or from "Terms & Conditions:" up to the page number 1 in printing? Most printers have non printable ranges on top, left and right but at least on bottom of the paper size. That is because if that would not be so, the print head would put ink outside the paper onto the transport  roller and so polluting the transport  roller. How big the non printable ranges will be depends on the used printer. But do taking as a fact, that no one will be able printing to a page up to the very last paper edge using `Word`.

Comment: See also [error message when you try to print a document in which margins of section are set outside the printable area of the page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/290964/you-receive-an-error-message-when-you-try-to-print-a-document-in-which). So `Word` will tell you the non printable ranges of your printer while using page setup dialog box, clicking margins, OK and then Fix.

Comment: Yes sir that error of 'non-printing range' was coming. I had then fixed it by applying margin of '0.3 cm'. Page size in .docx & printer both is A4. But the next issue is, when I am printing this document, it is getting printed till 'invoice amount in words' row. I've not added any other spaces in the bottom part then also after 'invoice amount' the page is printed blank and the next content is printed on another page. I checked this in 2 printers. So is there any setting that I can do to avoid this? Will it be like there is any space left in the bottom part or I need to set something via code?